# Spring-Data Repository @Query by class with generic class

Tags: java, spring, generics, jpa, spring-data-jpa

assuming I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Word { ... }

@Entity
public class Noun extends Word { ... }

@Entity
public class Verb extends Word { ... }
```

(Plus the usual Disriminator- and Join-Strategy stuff, simply assume that the entities work fine, which they do.)

I tried ...

```
public interface WordRepository extends CrudRepository<Word, Long>{

     @Query("SELECT x FROM Word x WHERE type(x) = ?1")
     <T extends Word> List<T> findByClass(Class<T> clz);

}
```

...but this gives me an exception, caused by:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [1] [SELECT x FROM Word x WHERE type(x) = ?1]
```

One solution is to **replace** `Class<T>` with `Class<?>`, then the code works, but obviously that's not type-safe anymore since then I can write...

```
List<Verb> verbs = repository.findByClass(Noun.class);
```

...which runs, but obviously throws a `ClassCastException` whenever I try to access the `verbs (`since all the objects in the list are actually `Nouns`, not `Verbs`)

Is there any way to write this type-safe with spring-data, preferably without hardcoding all types into their own methods (`findNouns`, `findVerbs`, etc.) or defining `Repositories` for all types?

Edit: The problem seems to be the `Parameter.isDynamicProjectionParameter(MethodParameter)` method, that seems to define a special behavior for `Class<T>` parameters, so they are only used for dynamic parameters but cannot be given into the query itself. Hm. Wish anyone had a way around that.

Comment: As a workaround, you could simply write this as a custom repository method, where you would create and execute the query by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As a workaround I can also live with the missing type safety, since it's currently just for a private project of mine, but I was hoping there was something I was simply missing. If nothing comes forward, perhaps I'll open a ticket at their issue tracker.

Comment: Any reason why `interface WordRepository<T extends Word> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {}` and then `interface VerbRepository extends WordRepository<Verb> {}` does not work for you? You can then use the in-built `findAll` method from `CrudRepository`.

Comment: Because then I have to use different repositories instad of simply using another parameter, which would be simpler, imho, in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I just faced the same issue. For your/every other user´s information i filed a spring data jpa issue, which you folks can follow here:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1257